# jQuery Horizontal Accordion and animation problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a horizontal accordion these days.

You can see that there is a small "jump" of the color boxes on right hand side when clicking the color box. I don't know why the small "jump" occurs.

I then use animate instead of hide and show to try to solve the problem.

Even if the width animates to 0px, the element still has a few pixels, so I try to hide it after the animation. But the hide() function doesn't do anything. Why?

During debugging, I find that the alert("good") runs right before the animation ends. Why?

Thank you for answering my questions.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.accordion {    padding: 3px;   margin: 0px;    float: left;    width: 300px;}
.accordionTitle {   cursor: pointer;    padding: 3px;   margin: 0px;    float: left;width:20px; height:150px; }
.clearBoth { clear: both; }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    var elementToTransform = ".accordion" 
    $(elementToTransform).hide();
    var currentAccordionPanel = ($(".currentAccordionPanel").show())[0];
    $(".accordionTitle").click(function() {
        if ($(this).next(elementToTransform)[0] != currentAccordionPanel)
            {
                $(currentAccordionPanel).hide(400);
                $(this).next(elementToTransform).show(400);
                /*$(currentAccordionPanel).animate({width:"0px"},{duration:200,queue:false},{},function(){alert("good")});
                $(this).next(elementToTransform).animate({width:"300px"},{duration:200,queue:false});
                      $(currentAccordionPanel).hide(); // the element still has few pixels even width animates to 0, so I hide it
*/
                currentAccordionPanel = $(this).next(elementToTransform)[0];
            }

    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:800px;">
    <div id="cat1">
        <div class="accordionTitle" style="background:blue">1</div>
        <div class="accordion currentAccordionPanel" id="p1">content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cat2">
        <div class="accordionTitle" style="background:red">2</div>
        <div class="accordion" id="p2">content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cat3">
        <div class="accordionTitle" style="background:yellow">3</div>
        <div class="accordion" id="p3">content 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cat4">
        <div class="accordionTitle" style="background:green">4</div>
        <div class="accordion" id="p4">content 4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cat5">
        <div class="accordionTitle" style="background:red">5</div>
        <div class="accordion" id="p5">content 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add the following style to the accordion and accordionTitle classes:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

That would at least solve the problem of the width not going to zero.